# How to extract logs between two time stamps, line may or may not start with datetime

Tags: text-processing, awk

How to extract logs between two time stamps, line may or may not start with datetime.
I am trying below and it is only extracting the lines that starts with datetime only. Datetime format is `2014-04-07 23:00`

```
$ awk \
  '$0 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/
      {
        if ($1" "$2 >= "2014-04-07 23:00")     p=1;
        if ($1" "$2 >= "2014-04-08 02:00")  p=0;
      }
    p { print $0 }' log
```

Here is my sample data:

```
2014-04-07 22:59:10.001 agaggagag  
gagagg 
2014-04-07 23:40:33.345 aegsgssdh  
wqtqttqtqtq  
post  
agggsdgg  
2014-04-08 01:00:54.777 ggsdgwettwetewt  
cvdgwetegdkiytitityi  
error 
2014-04-08 02:02:22.009 qwwqtwtwebbcbewdhshsdh  
asgsaftewtewt  
1253536443755475  
2014-04-08 10:55:34.934 etwtewtewppip  
jklhlljkjvncncmmm  
sghywywywywyw
```

I want to extract all data between `2014-04-07 23:00` and `2014-04-08 02:00`

Comment: The code you posted also prints lines that don't start with a datetime. What is the problem with it?

Comment: An example of the data that you're trying to parse would be extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

The RE in the pattern match starts with `^` which binds the expression to the start of the line. If you want match your expression anywhere you need to remove it.

Your `if...` statements assume that the date/time fields are in `$1` and `$2`, which are also (by definition) not necessarily true. Try this instead (it's untested because I don't have a sample of your data)

```
awk '
    {
        if (match($0, /\<[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\>/))
        {
            s = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)            
            if (s >= "2014-04-07 23:00") p=1
            if (s >= "2014-04-08 02:00") p=0
        }
    }
    p { print $0 }
' log
```

Output from sample data

```
2014-04-07 23:40:33.345 aegsgssdh
wqtqttqtqtq
post
agggsdgg
2014-04-08 01:00:54.777 ggsdgwettwetewt
cvdgwetegdkiytitityi
error
```

Comment: Roaima, Thanks for the reply. I tried above and not getting the desired output. I added sample data as requested.

Comment: @Krish works for me. It provides output as defined in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the beginning of the script to either

```
$ awk \
  '$0 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/ \
      {
           ︙
```

or

```
$ awk \
  '$0 ~ /^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/    {
           ︙
```

Currently, your script has three statements:

1. If the line matches `/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/`, print it (default action).
2. For all lines (default condition), set `p` to 1 if `$1 $2` is within the range and 0 if it is not.
3. If `p` is non-zero, print the line.

So *every* line that looks like a date-time stamp
(based on your regexp) gets printed based on statement 1. 
And every line that contains a date-time stamp
within the selection range gets printed
based on the interaction between statements 2 and 3.

Obviously, you want to bind condition 1 and statement 2 together.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple script for your your purpose. Check is this helpful for you

> [upkar@server2 one]# cat logxtract.sh
>
> L1=$(grep -n "2014-04-07 23:[0-9][0-9]" log | awk -F":" '{print $1}')
>
> L2=$(grep -n "2014-04-08 02:[0-9][0-9]" log | awk -F":" '{print $1}')
>
> sed -n $L1,"$L2"p log

**Output of the script**

> [upkar@server2 one]# sh logxtract.sh

```
2014-04-07 23:40:33.345 aegsgssdh

wqtqttqtqtq

post

agggsdgg

2014-04-08 01:00:54.777 ggsdgwettwetewt

cvdgwetegdkiytitityi

error

2014-04-08 02:02:22.009 qwwqtwtwebbcbewdhshsdh
```